# linked lists : student database >> help needed

Tags: database, list, linked-list

in need help to write the right code plz 
q:Write a program which organizes a simple database of student information.

The program should allow the user to enter a sequence of student data records. Each student data record has three fields: first name, last name, and age. The user should be able to perform the following 4 operations: 1) enter a record, 2) delete a record, 3) print all records, and 4) sort all records. All 4 options should be printed at the beginning. The user should receive a prompt where he/she can enter the number coresponding to the operation he wants to perform. The enter a record operation will prompt the user to type in three strings on the same line, one string per field. The print all records operation should print each record on a different line. The sort all records operation should sort based on last name.

the code i wrote is: (disply and add are working, but delete and sorting are not!)

```
        #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<malloc.h>


     struct student
      {
         char fname[29];
         char lname[29];
         int age;
         struct student *next;
      };

      int main()
      {
        int i,n,ch,ps,x,k;
        k=0;
      struct student *h,*t,*t1,*w,*q;
      h=NULL;

      printf("\n/* student data records*/");


    while(1)
     {
          printf("\n1.display\n2:add\n3.delete\n4.exit\n5.sort by first name\n");
            printf("\nenter your choice=");
          scanf("%d",&ch);
          switch(ch)
    {
    case 1:
      if(h==NULL)
       {
        printf("no records are available");
      }
      w=h;
      while(w!=NULL)
     {
        printf("\nfirst name of a student:%s\nlast name of a student:%s\nage of a student:%d\n",
      w->fname,w->lname,w->age);
      w=w->next;
     }
    break;

    case 2:
       printf("\nenter the new record=\t");
       if(h==NULL)
     {
      h=t=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
       printf("\nfirst Name of a student:\t");
        scanf("%s",&t->fname);
        printf("\nlast Name of a student:\t");
        scanf("%s",&t->lname);
        printf("\nage of a student:\t");
        scanf("%d",&t->age);
       t->next=NULL;
    break;
    }
    else
      {
        t1=(struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
        printf("\nFirst Name of a student:\t");
        scanf("%s",&t1->fname);
        printf("\nlast Name of a student:\t");
        scanf("%s",&t1->lname);
        printf("\nage of a student:\t");
        scanf("%d",&t1->age);
        t1->next=t->next;
        t->next=t1;
        t=t1;
    }
    break;

    case 3:
        printf("enter name of student whos record is to be deleted=\n");
        scanf("%d",&ps);
        t=h;
     while(t->fname!=ps-1)
       {
         t=t->next;
        }
         t1=t->next;
         t->next=t1->next;
         free(t1);
     break;

    case 4:
     exit(0);
     break;

    case 5:
    printf("not working yet");
    {
    void sort( student[],int n)
     { int i,j,comp=0,passes=0;
       student temp;
       for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        {
           passes++;
           for(j=0;j<n-i;j++)
        {      comp++;
               if(st[j].lname < st[j+1].lname)
               {  temp=st[j];
                  st[j]=st[j+1];
                  st[j+1]=temp;
               }
        }
        }
     }
    }
    break;
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case 5, you're using student as the name of an array (or maybe the type of an array with no name?) AND as the type of temp; then you never use student, but do use st, which doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.  I'm surprised that this compiled...

First guess at a solution: maybe you mean the parameter to sort() to be `student st[]` ?

Second guess: it DOESN'T compile, and you actually haven't tried to write the sort code for a linked list.

Try this approach: First get delete to work, but write it so that it optionally returns the "deleted" record instead of free-ing it.  Then you can sort by building a new list to replace the old one, by repeatedly finding and not-quite deleting the largest element left in the old list, and adding that to the new one, until the old list has been exhausted.

As for delete not working, you didn't give any details, but I noticed that `h` never changes, and you assume that the name searched for will be found.

Comment: i tried first to sort the linked list alphabetically, but i couldnt ,so i thought maybe sorting the array fname[] may do the job and sort the names,but that didnt help :(  if u know how to sort the names using linked lists, can u plz write the code or correct mine? thanks alot